# Next.js 13 throws 3 errors out of the box after starting a new project

Tags: reactjs, next.js

It's my first time working with a technology in beta so maybe this is to be expected and I should just ignore these erros for now?
I'm also extremely new to Next.js.

I've ran `npx create-next-app@latest front --typescript -` to create a new directory for my app code (will keep my API separated as there's also an electron app that needs to communicate with it).

1. I chose no for using the `src/` directory.
2. I chose yes for the experimental `/app` directory.
3. I simply clicked enter and skipped when asked about configuring an import alias.

When the project was built, I ran `npm run dev` and I am getting 3 errors out of the box.

Errors are-

Two of this:

```
Error: Hydration failed because the initial UI does not match what was rendered on the server.

Warning: Expected server HTML to contain a matching <main> in <body>.

See more info here: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/react-hydration-error
```

One of this:

```
Error: There was an error while hydrating. Because the error happened outside of a Suspense boundary, the entire root will switch to client rendering.
```

This is the complete log from the console:

````
    at main
    at ScrollAndFocusHandler (webpack-internal:///(app-client)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/layout-router.js:149:1)
    at InnerLayoutRouter (webpack-internal:///(app-client)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/layout-router.js:178:11)
    at RedirectErrorBoundary (webpack-internal:///(app-client)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/layout-router.js:334:9)
    at RedirectBoundary (webpack-internal:///(app-client)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/layout-router.js:341:11)
    at NotFoundErrorBoundary (webpack-internal:///(app-client)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/layout-router.js:370:9)
    at NotFoundBoundary (webpack-internal:///(app-client)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/layout-router.js:377:11)
    at LoadingBoundary (webpack-internal:///(app-client)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/layout-router.js:289:11)
    at ErrorBoundary (webpack-internal:///(app-client)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/error-boundary.js:76:11)
    at RenderFromTemplateContext (webpack-internal:///(app-client)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/render-from-template-context.js:12:34)
    at OuterLayoutRouter (webpack-internal:///(app-client)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/layout-router.js:20:11)
    at body
    at html
    at ReactDevOverlay (webpack-internal:///(app-client)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/react-dev-overlay/internal/ReactDevOverlay.js:58:9)
    at HotReload (webpack-internal:///(app-client)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/react-dev-overlay/hot-reloader-client.js:19:11)
    at Router (webpack-internal:///(app-client)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/app-router.js:99:11)
    at ErrorBoundaryHandler (webpack-internal:///(app-client)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/error-boundary.js:63:9)
    at ErrorBoundary (webpack-internal:///(app-client)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/error-boundary.js:76:11)
    at AppRouter (webpack-internal:///(app-client)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/app-router.js:20:13)
    at ServerRoot (webpack-internal:///(app-client)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/app-index.js:126:11)
    at RSCComponent
    at Root (webpack-internal:///(app-client)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/app-index.js:143:11)
overrideMethod @ react_devtools_backend.js:4012
console.error @ hydration-error-info.js?32aa:24
printWarning @ react-dom.development.js?d37d:94
error @ react-dom.development.js?d37d:68
warnForInsertedHydratedElement @ react-dom.development.js?d37d:10659
didNotFindHydratableInstance @ react-dom.development.js?d37d:13436
warnNonhydratedInstance @ react-dom.development.js?d37d:14601
tryToClaimNextHydratableInstance @ react-dom.development.js?d37d:14775
updateHostComponent @ react-dom.development.js?d37d:23001
beginWork @ react-dom.development.js?d37d:24831
beginWork$1 @ react-dom.development.js?d37d:32185
performUnitOfWork @ react-dom.development.js?d37d:31082
workLoopConcurrent @ react-dom.development.js?d37d:31068
renderRootConcurrent @ react-dom.development.js?d37d:31026
performConcurrentWorkOnRoot @ react-dom.development.js?d37d:29983
workLoop @ index.js?91dc:10
flushWork @ index.js?91dc:10
performWorkUntilDeadline @ index.js?91dc:10
react-dom.development.js?d37d:14726 Uncaught Error: Hydration failed because the initial UI does not match what was rendered on the server.
    at throwOnHydrationMismatch (webpack-internal:///(:3000/app-client)/./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:14726:9)
    at tryToClaimNextHydratableInstance (webpack-internal:///(:3000/app-client)/./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:14776:7)
    at updateHostComponent (webpack-internal:///(:3000/app-client)/./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:22996:5)
    at beginWork (webpack-internal:///(:3000/app-client)/./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:24826:14)
    at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (webpack-internal:///(:3000/app-client)/./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:4246:14)
    at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (webpack-internal:///(:3000/app-client)/./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:4295:16)
    at invokeGuardedCallback (webpack-internal:///(:3000/app-client)/./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:4359:31)
    at beginWork$1 (webpack-internal:///(:3000/app-client)/./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:32202:7)
    at performUnitOfWork (webpack-internal:///(:3000/app-client)/./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:31077:12)
    at workLoopConcurrent (webpack-internal:///(:3000/app-client)/./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:31063:5)
    at renderRootConcurrent (webpack-internal:///(:3000/app-client)/./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:31021:7)
    at performConcurrentWorkOnRoot (webpack-internal:///(:3000/app-client)/./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:29978:38)
    at workLoop (webpack-internal:///(:3000/app-client)/./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/scheduler/index.js:11:3897)
    at flushWork (webpack-internal:///(:3000/app-client)/./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/scheduler/index.js:11:3606)
    at MessagePort.performWorkUntilDeadline (webpack-internal:///(:3000/app-client)/./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/scheduler/index.js:11:1787)
throwOnHydrationMismatch @ react-dom.development.js?d37d:14726
tryToClaimNextHydratableInstance @ react-dom.development.js?d37d:14776
updateHostComponent @ react-dom.development.js?d37d:23001
beginWork @ react-dom.development.js?d37d:24831
callCallback @ react-dom.development.js?d37d:4246
invokeGuardedCallbackDev @ react-dom.development.js?d37d:4295
invokeGuardedCallback @ react-dom.development.js?d37d:4359
beginWork$1 @ react-dom.development.js?d37d:32207
performUnitOfWork @ react-dom.development.js?d37d:31082
workLoopConcurrent @ react-dom.development.js?d37d:31068
renderRootConcurrent @ react-dom.development.js?d37d:31026
performConcurrentWorkOnRoot @ react-dom.development.js?d37d:29983
workLoop @ index.js?91dc:10
flushWork @ index.js?91dc:10
performWorkUntilDeadline @ index.js?91dc:10
react_devtools_backend.js:4012 Warning: An error occurred during hydration. The server HTML was replaced with client content in <#document>.
overrideMethod @ react_devtools_backend.js:4012
console.error @ hydration-error-info.js?32aa:24
printWarning @ react-dom.development.js?d37d:94
error @ react-dom.development.js?d37d:68
errorHydratingContainer @ react-dom.development.js?d37d:13451
recoverFromConcurrentError @ react-dom.development.js?d37d:30105
performConcurrentWorkOnRoot @ react-dom.development.js?d37d:29996
workLoop @ index.js?91dc:10
flushWork @ index.js?91dc:10
performWorkUntilDeadline @ index.js?91dc:10
react_devtools_backend.js:4012 Warning: You are accessing "digest" from the errorInfo object passed to onRecoverableError. This property is deprecated and will be removed in a future version of React. To access the digest of an Error look for this property on the Error instance itself.
overrideMethod @ react_devtools_backend.js:4012
console.error @ hydration-error-info.js?32aa:24
printWarning @ react-dom.development.js?d37d:94
error @ react-dom.development.js?d37d:68
get @ react-dom.development.js?d37d:31630
onRecoverableError @ on-recoverable-error.js?eb92:8
commitRootImpl @ react-dom.development.js?d37d:31567
commitRoot @ react-dom.development.js?d37d:31330
finishConcurrentRender @ react-dom.development.js?d37d:30263
performConcurrentWorkOnRoot @ react-dom.development.js?d37d:30055
workLoop @ index.js?91dc:10
flushWork @ index.js?91dc:10
performWorkUntilDeadline @ index.js?91dc:10
on-recoverable-error.js?eb92:17 Uncaught Error: Hydration failed because the initial UI does not match what was rendered on the server.
    at throwOnHydrationMismatch (webpack-internal:///(:3000/app-client)/./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:14726:9)
    at tryToClaimNextHydratableInstance (webpack-internal:///(:3000/app-client)/./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:14776:7)
    at updateHostComponent (webpack-internal:///(:3000/app-client)/./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:22996:5)
    at beginWork (webpack-internal:///(:3000/app-client)/./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:24826:14)
    at beginWork$1 (webpack-internal:///(:3000/app-client)/./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:32180:14)
    at performUnitOfWork (webpack-internal:///(:3000/app-client)/./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:31077:12)
    at workLoopConcurrent (webpack-internal:///(:3000/app-client)/./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:31063:5)
    at renderRootConcurrent (webpack-internal:///(:3000/app-client)/./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:31021:7)
    at performConcurrentWorkOnRoot (webpack-internal:///(:3000/app-client)/./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:29978:38)
    at workLoop (webpack-internal:///(:3000/app-client)/./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/scheduler/index.js:11:3897)
    at flushWork (webpack-internal:///(:3000/app-client)/./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/scheduler/index.js:11:3606)
    at MessagePort.performWorkUntilDeadline (webpack-internal:///(:3000/app-client)/./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/scheduler/index.js:11:1787)
throwOnHydrationMismatch @ react-dom.development.js?d37d:14726
tryToClaimNextHydratableInstance @ react-dom.development.js?d37d:14776
updateHostComponent @ react-dom.development.js?d37d:23001
beginWork @ react-dom.development.js?d37d:24831
beginWork$1 @ react-dom.development.js?d37d:32185
performUnitOfWork @ react-dom.development.js?d37d:31082
workLoopConcurrent @ react-dom.development.js?d37d:31068
renderRootConcurrent @ react-dom.development.js?d37d:31026
performConcurrentWorkOnRoot @ react-dom.development.js?d37d:29983
workLoop @ index.js?91dc:10
flushWork @ index.js?91dc:10
performWorkUntilDeadline @ index.js?91dc:10
react_devtools_backend.js:4012 Warning: You are accessing "digest" from the errorInfo object passed to onRecoverableError. This property is deprecated and will be removed in a future version of React. To access the digest of an Error look for this property on the Error instance itself.
overrideMethod @ react_devtools_backend.js:4012
console.error @ hydration-error-info.js?32aa:24
printWarning @ react-dom.development.js?d37d:94
error @ react-dom.development.js?d37d:68
get @ react-dom.development.js?d37d:31630
onRecoverableError @ on-recoverable-error.js?eb92:8
commitRootImpl @ react-dom.development.js?d37d:31567
commitRoot @ react-dom.development.js?d37d:31330
finishConcurrentRender @ react-dom.development.js?d37d:30263
performConcurrentWorkOnRoot @ react-dom.development.js?d37d:30055
workLoop @ index.js?91dc:10
flushWork @ index.js?91dc:10
performWorkUntilDeadline @ index.js?91dc:10
on-recoverable-error.js?eb92:17 Uncaught Error: Hydration failed because the initial UI does not match what was rendered on the server.
    at throwOnHydrationMismatch (webpack-internal:///(:3000/app-client)/./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:14726:9)
    at tryToClaimNextHydratableInstance (webpack-internal:///(:3000/app-client)/./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:14776:7)
    at updateHostComponent (webpack-internal:///(:3000/app-client)/./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:22996:5)
    at beginWork (webpack-internal:///(:3000/app-client)/./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:24826:14)
    at beginWork$1 (webpack-internal:///(:3000/app-client)/./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:32180:14)
    at performUnitOfWork (webpack-internal:///(:3000/app-client)/./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:31077:12)
    at workLoopConcurrent (webpack-internal:///(:3000/app-client)/./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:31063:5)
    at renderRootConcurrent (webpack-internal:///(:3000/app-client)/./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:31021:7)
    at performConcurrentWorkOnRoot (webpack-internal:///(:3000/app-client)/./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:29978:38)
    at workLoop (webpack-internal:///(:3000/app-client)/./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/scheduler/index.js:11:3897)
    at flushWork (webpack-internal:///(:3000/app-client)/./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/scheduler/index.js:11:3606)
    at MessagePort.performWorkUntilDeadline (webpack-internal:///(:3000/app-client)/./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/scheduler/index.js:11:1787)
throwOnHydrationMismatch @ react-dom.development.js?d37d:14726
tryToClaimNextHydratableInstance @ react-dom.development.js?d37d:14776
updateHostComponent @ react-dom.development.js?d37d:23001
beginWork @ react-dom.development.js?d37d:24831
beginWork$1 @ react-dom.development.js?d37d:32185
performUnitOfWork @ react-dom.development.js?d37d:31082
workLoopConcurrent @ react-dom.development.js?d37d:31068
renderRootConcurrent @ react-dom.development.js?d37d:31026
performConcurrentWorkOnRoot @ react-dom.development.js?d37d:29983
workLoop @ index.js?91dc:10
flushWork @ index.js?91dc:10
performWorkUntilDeadline @ index.js?91dc:10
react_devtools_backend.js:4012 Warning: You are accessing "digest" from the errorInfo object passed to onRecoverableError. This property is deprecated and will be removed in a future version of React. To access the digest of an Error look for this property on the Error instance itself.
overrideMethod @ react_devtools_backend.js:4012
console.error @ hydration-error-info.js?32aa:24
printWarning @ react-dom.development.js?d37d:94
error @ react-dom.development.js?d37d:68
get @ react-dom.development.js?d37d:31630
onRecoverableError @ on-recoverable-error.js?eb92:8
commitRootImpl @ react-dom.development.js?d37d:31567
commitRoot @ react-dom.development.js?d37d:31330
finishConcurrentRender @ react-dom.development.js?d37d:30263
performConcurrentWorkOnRoot @ react-dom.development.js?d37d:30055
workLoop @ index.js?91dc:10
flushWork @ index.js?91dc:10
performWorkUntilDeadline @ index.js?91dc:10
on-recoverable-error.js?eb92:17 Uncaught Error: Hydration failed because the initial UI does not match what was rendered on the server.
    at throwOnHydrationMismatch (webpack-internal:///(:3000/app-client)/./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:14726:9)
    at tryToClaimNextHydratableInstance (webpack-internal:///(:3000/app-client)/./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:14776:7)
    at updateHostComponent (webpack-internal:///(:3000/app-client)/./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:22996:5)
    at beginWork (webpack-internal:///(:3000/app-client)/./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:24826:14)
    at beginWork$1 (webpack-internal:///(:3000/app-client)/./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:32180:14)
    at performUnitOfWork (webpack-internal:///(:3000/app-client)/./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:31077:12)
    at workLoopConcurrent (webpack-internal:///(:3000/app-client)/./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:31063:5)
    at renderRootConcurrent (webpack-internal:///(:3000/app-client)/./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:31021:7)
    at performConcurrentWorkOnRoot (webpack-internal:///(:3000/app-client)/./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:29978:38)
    at workLoop (webpack-internal:///(:3000/app-client)/./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/scheduler/index.js:11:3897)
    at flushWork (webpack-internal:///(:3000/app-client)/./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/scheduler/index.js:11:3606)
    at MessagePort.performWorkUntilDeadline (webpack-internal:///(:3000/app-client)/./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/scheduler/index.js:11:1787)
throwOnHydrationMismatch @ react-dom.development.js?d37d:14726
tryToClaimNextHydratableInstance @ react-dom.development.js?d37d:14776
updateHostComponent @ react-dom.development.js?d37d:23001
beginWork @ react-dom.development.js?d37d:24831
beginWork$1 @ react-dom.development.js?d37d:32185
performUnitOfWork @ react-dom.development.js?d37d:31082
workLoopConcurrent @ react-dom.development.js?d37d:31068
renderRootConcurrent @ react-dom.development.js?d37d:31026
performConcurrentWorkOnRoot @ react-dom.development.js?d37d:29983
workLoop @ index.js?91dc:10
flushWork @ index.js?91dc:10
performWorkUntilDeadline @ index.js?91dc:10
react_devtools_backend.js:4012 Warning: You are accessing "digest" from the errorInfo object passed to onRecoverableError. This property is deprecated and will be removed in a future version of React. To access the digest of an Error look for this property on the Error instance itself.
overrideMethod @ react_devtools_backend.js:4012
console.error @ hydration-error-info.js?32aa:24
printWarning @ react-dom.development.js?d37d:94
error @ react-dom.development.js?d37d:68
get @ react-dom.development.js?d37d:31630
onRecoverableError @ on-recoverable-error.js?eb92:8
commitRootImpl @ react-dom.development.js?d37d:31567
commitRoot @ react-dom.development.js?d37d:31330
finishConcurrentRender @ react-dom.development.js?d37d:30263
performConcurrentWorkOnRoot @ react-dom.development.js?d37d:30055
workLoop @ index.js?91dc:10
flushWork @ index.js?91dc:10
performWorkUntilDeadline @ index.js?91dc:10
react-dom.development.js?d37d:22948 Uncaught Error: There was an error while hydrating. Because the error happened outside of a Suspense boundary, the entire root will switch to client rendering.
    at updateHostRoot (webpack-internal:///(:3000/app-client)/./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:22943:57)
    at beginWork (webpack-internal:///(:3000/app-client)/./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:24809:14)
    at beginWork$1 (webpack-internal:///(:3000/app-client)/./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:32180:14)
    at performUnitOfWork (webpack-internal:///(:3000/app-client)/./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:31077:12)
    at workLoopSync (webpack-internal:///(:3000/app-client)/./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:30886:5)
    at renderRootSync (webpack-internal:///(:3000/app-client)/./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:30851:7)
    at recoverFromConcurrentError (webpack-internal:///(:3000/app-client)/./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:30104:20)
    at performConcurrentWorkOnRoot (webpack-internal:///(:3000/app-client)/./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:29991:22)
    at workLoop (webpack-internal:///(:3000/app-client)/./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/scheduler/index.js:11:3897)
    at flushWork (webpack-internal:///(:3000/app-client)/./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/scheduler/index.js:11:3606)
    at MessagePort.performWorkUntilDeadline (webpack-internal:///(:3000/app-client)/./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/scheduler/index.js:11:1787)```
````

Comment: what version of nextjs do you have specified in your package.json?

Comment: @thedanotto Since posting this I've built a few projects without this issue, so I guess it's been fixed.

Answer (score 1):

In Next.js 13, it is not allowed to have certain elements as children of other elements, such as having a div inside a p tag etc.

This is because it can cause issues with the HTML structure and accessibility of the page, and can also lead to unexpected rendering behavior.

To avoid this issue, you should make sure that your components generate HTML that conforms to the rules of the DOM structure. For example, instead of using a div inside a p tag, you can use a span or other appropriate tag to achieve the same visual effect. Check all page, layout and other files.

Answer (score 0):

Although I did not start from a fresh project, I resolved this error be removing every custom components from the Root layout:

```
export async function generateStaticParams() {
  return i18n.locales.map((locale) => ({ lang: locale }));
}

export default function Root({
  children,
  params,
}: {
  children: React.ReactNode;
  params: { lang: string };
}) {
  return (
    <html lang={params.lang} className="overflow-hidden">
      <body className="bg-night-500">{children}</body>
    </html>
  );
}
```

Then I moved all the custom components I used in the root layout to a sub layout:[image]

More info can be found in the [docs](https://beta.nextjs.org/docs/routing/pages-and-layouts#root-layout-required)

Im still not sure why you get this error from a fresh project but this might help you debug your problem.

Comment: To properly fix a problem one needs first to understand the root cause. This seem not to be the case here.